# Compile errors with #include <string> in Cocoa App

Tags: xcode, stl

I am trying to compile a Cocoa app in xcode 4.0 and I'm getting this error...

```
fatal error: 'string' file not found
```

...when trying to compile to .pch file on this line:

```
#include <string>
```

I have another xcode project that does the same thing, but does not get the error.  I have scoured the build settings for some different, but I can't find one.  The only difference is that the project that compiles OK was started as a command line project, not a Cocoa project, but the build setting are the same.

The target OS is Mac OS X 10.6

The error happens when compiling the precompiled header and doesn't get to any of the other files.  The only framework that the compiling version has is Foundation.framework and the non-compiling one has it as well.

Why is it not finding  in one project and not the other?  Any advice?

Comment: What programming language is your app written in? Isn't `<string>` a C++ thing, not an Objective-C thing?

Comment: You can use the stl in objective-c++.  Just name your files .mm.  I completely started over with this project from a fresh cocoa app template and it works fine now.

Answer (score 14):

What is the extension of your source files? If it is ".m", try to change it to obj-cpp ".mm", so that Xcode will deduce correct language. 
Or just put c++-specific headers inside "#ifdef __cplusplus" block

**Update**

The guard must exist for each language compiled in the project because this specific include is in the pch. IOW, if it were all c++ and/or objc++ there would be no error. Evidently, there is at least one file that does not recognize C++ (e.g. C or ObjC sources are also compiled in the target). Therefore, you simply guard it like so:

```
// MONPrefix.pch

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>
#endif

// same for objc, so your C and C++ sources compile with no error:
#ifdef __OBJC__
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Comment: +1 *"just put c++-specific headers inside "#ifdef __cplusplus" block"* -- is the right solution -- but the guard must exist for each language compiled in the project because this specific include is in the pch. iow, if it were all c++ and/or objc++ there would be no error. evidently, there is at least one file that does not recognize c++ (e.g. c or objc). will update myself -- i now see this is months old :)

Comment: This helped me figure out how to properly set up a Prefix.pch for a Cocos2D-X project. Wrapping the C++ specific stuff in "#ifdef __cplusplus" works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a C++ header (for std::string).  If you are looking for stuff like `strcpy`  you need to include `string.h`