# XCode cannnot use c++ static libraries in precompile header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I set prefix header "pch.h" to BuildSettings in Xcode 11.

pch.h

```
#include <string>
```

Error occurred "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group".

I guess compiler problem used precompile in Xcode.
Can I use precompile header with libc++??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile errors with #include <string> in Cocoa App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542850/compile-errors-with-include-string-in-cocoa-app)

Comment: Great! Thank you.
I might solve my problem.